# Why are these simple Laravel queries so slow?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timeout

The application was working perfectly and all of a sudden I started receiving a timeout error.
The original code is not mine and when this problem started occurring I became forced to optimize the application.

**Fixes I tried:**

- Caching the "current template", "template options" and "settings" database data in a middleware. This increased the speed drastically because each database row was fetched using its own query (so say we have 18 template options = 18 database queries)
- Removing any changes I made. Did not work as well, meaning the problem is somewhere else.
- Upgrading my local MySQL server using an old online installer for Windows.
- Removing the "company" global scope, which made me 100% sure the scope has nothing to do with it.
- Running the MySQL queries in the MySQL console, they were fast.

---

**The Company Middleware**: Responsible for caching the database data

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!isset($GLOBALS['CURRENT_TEMPLATE']) || !($GLOBALS['CURRENT_TEMPLATE'] ?? null) instanceof \App\Template) {        
            $GLOBALS['CURRENT_TEMPLATE'] = \App\Template::where('enabled',1)->first();;
        }

        if (!isset($GLOBALS['SETTINGS']) || !($GLOBALS['SETTINGS'] ?? null) instanceof Collection) {
            $GLOBALS['SETTINGS'] = \App\Setting::all(); // Changed this just now in code, it had a copy&paste typo, but no impact at all (used to be \App\Template::all())
        }

        if (!isset($GLOBALS['TEMPLATE_OPTIONS']) || !($GLOBALS['TEMPLATE_OPTIONS'] ?? null) instanceof Collection) {
            $GLOBALS['TEMPLATE_OPTIONS'] = $GLOBALS['CURRENT_TEMPLATE']->templateOptions()->get();
        }

        if (!isset($GLOBALS['HEADER_MENU']) || !($GLOBALS['HEADER_MENU'] ?? null) instanceof Collection) {
            $GLOBALS['HEADER_MENU'] = \App\HeaderMenu::all();
        }

        if (!isset($GLOBALS['FOOTER_MENU']) || !($GLOBALS['FOOTER_MENU'] ?? null) instanceof Collection) {
            $GLOBALS['FOOTER_MENU'] = \App\FooterMenu::all();
        }

        if(class_exists('\App\Helper') && method_exists(new \App\Helper(), 'boot')){
            \App\Helper::boot();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

I believe the problem is ongoing somewhere in the queries but I am not sure where yet. I tried debugging with XDebug, reviewing Laravel Debugbar & Clockwork logs and finally Laravel Telescope.

---

**Laravel Telescope Request Log**
[image]

**Laravel Telescope Request Queries Log**
[image]

> PS: I added the row count per query in this screenshot.

I am currently still working on optimizing the code but as you have already seen, even removing duplicate queries may not be a solution because queries are taking too long anyways.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions for other ways I should debug this problem or even better if you have a solution for it. Please do not hesitate to ask for any more details you may need. Thank you!

### UPDATE

After optimizing the queries and removing duplicates, the result is still the same. Queries are taking over **16000ms**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need some indexes.

```
INDEX(company_id, enabled)
INDEX(template_id)
INDEX(slug)
```

When `LIMIT` is used without `ORDER BY`, the row you get is unpredictable.

(Please use text, not images, to display code.)